Android Compose PagingData<T> Data update
fun getPost() = viewModelScope.launch {
    _getPostLoading.value = true
    _postDataList.value = PagingData.empty()
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = POST_SIZE,
            enablePlaceholders = true
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            PostPagingSource(postRepository, tokenManager)
        }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).collectLatest {
        _postDataList.value = it
        _getPostLoading.value = false
    }
}

Is it possible to change the value received after paging?
For example, if you click Like on a post with the status PagingData, you can change the Like status of that post.
private val items = combine(_postDataList, removedItems, updatedItems) { all, removed, updated ->
    all.filter { it.postId !in removed }
        .map { updated.getOrDefault(key = it.postId, defaultValue = it) }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, PagingData.empty())

private fun removePost(post: PostData) {
    removedItems.update { setOf(post.postId) + post.postId }
}

private fun updatePost(post: PostData) {
    updatedItems.update { mapOf(post.postId to post) + (post.postId to post) }
}

fun getPost() = viewModelScope.launch {
    _getPostLoading.value = true
    _postDataList.value = PagingData.empty()
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = POST_SIZE,
            enablePlaceholders = true
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            PostPagingSource(postRepository, tokenManager)
        }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).collectLatest {
        _postDataList.value = it
        _getPostLoading.value = false
    }
}

fun postGood(post: PostData, userId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    kotlin.runCatching {
        postRepository.postGood(post.postId, userId)
    }.onSuccess { data ->
        post.goodStatus = data.goodStatus
        post.goodCounts = data.goodCounts
        updatePost(post)
    }.onFailure { e ->
        _postGoodState.emit(PostGoodState(isSuccess = false, error = e.message.toString()))
    }
}


If your like status is stored in whatever is under your postRepository, then it flows through the whole system already if you've actually written your PostPagingSource correctly to invalidate itself when your data changes.

Can you show me some example code?

@HamTory Please edit your post and also show the code of PostPagingSource.
